# What is the difference between declaring an char pointer and an array of chars in a function parameter list?

Tags: c

What is the difference between

```
foo(char* grid){}
```

And

```
foo(char grid[]){}
```

I have a program that I tested on both styles of the function parameters.  It seemed to work, but why does it work? What is the difference? Which one is more efficient,  and is the first one passing by reference?

Comment: The only 'efficiency' difference is that in the first case you type one character `*` instead of two `[]`.  This is not a material difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of a function parameter (and **only** in that case), they mean the same thing.

Note that C99 dropped the "implicit `int`" rule, so your examples should be something like:

```
void foo(char* grid){}
```

and

```
void foo(char grid[]){}
```

A parameter defined with an array type is "adjusted" to become a parameter of pointer type, pointing to the the element type of the array.

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.6.3 paragraph 7. (This is a freely available draft of the 2011 ISO C standard, PDF, 1.7 MB.)

(In all other contexts, a pointer declaration and an array declaration are different. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

All parameters in C are passed by value, not by reference. In this case, the value being passed happens to be a pointer value, which is the address of a `char` object.  For example, if you write:

```
char arr[10];
func(arr);
```

then the value being passed is `&arr[0]` (there's a separate language rule that says that array expressions are converted/adjusted to become pointer expressions in most but not all contexts).  Note that no information about the length of the array is passed; if you want to keep track of that, you'll have to do so explicitly.

C doesn't have pass-by-reference as a language feature.  Passing a pointer value is a way to emulate pass-by-reference.

Comment: but the question is am I actually passing the char array as a copy or reference ?

Comment: @Foxwhite5 You're passing a pointer to the first element of the array in both cases.

Comment: @Foxwhite5: You're passing a pointer to the first element of the array, and you're passing that pointer by copy. See my updated answer.